# How are compilation and ABI related?

Tags: compiler-construction, abi

How are compilation and ABI related?

Is a compiler's solely job to build Application Binary Interface (ABI) to OS and/or other applications?

About ABI, quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface):

> ABIs cover details such as data type,
>   size, and alignment; the calling
>   convention, which controls how
>   functions' arguments are passed and
>   return values retrieved; the system
>   call numbers and how an application
>   should make system calls to the
>   operating system; and in the case of a
>   complete operating system ABI, the
>   binary format of object files, program
>   libraries and so on.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ABI describes the features of the underlying OS, and includes some rules about how a program must be compiled. It's the compiler's job not to "build" the ABI, but to *conform* to the ABI as it creates executable code.

Comment: Thanks! So ABI is some specification belonging to OS, not to anything else including CPU and its instruction set, compiler, the language in which the source code is written in, and the program/executable?

Comment: Yes. It's fixed for the OS. An individual program does not contribute to it at all -- it only obeys it.

Comment: Thanks. I just added to my previous comments "not (belong) to anything else including CPU and its instruction set, compiler, the language in which the source code is written in, and the program/executable?".

Comment: CPU/instruction set would be considered a part of the ABI; the programming language would not, as the ABI is an interface used by all programs on a given system.

Answer (score 2):

Well, compiler may not follow the ABI completely. It had to emit valid machine code but for example it may not follow calling conventions for inner function calls. But of course, on the border between compiled code and OS the compiler should follow ABI.

Comment: Thanks! If a compiler does not follow ABI of a system completely, will the code compiled by it on the system be runnable on the system?

Comment: Depends on what you mean saying "completely". If compiled application doesn't conform the calling conventions at all even if calling library functions then calling such function will cause some error. Another case is if application doesn't conform to the executable/library format. That means the application will not run because loader fail loading such component. In other words, if compiled application doesn't follow ABI in places where it interacts with OS this will cause problems. It could be runnable but not working. Or working but not absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler has to output object file from source. This is dependent on the architecture, such as addressing mode availability, registers available, and such that are clarified within ABI. Also, OS is tightly coupled with architecture for performance reasons, so unless you are writing firmware, OS's calling convention for system calls and any such relevant details are part of ABI parcel.

Compiler replaces high-level source text by machine level opcodes and data. The output is required to comply depending on the tool-chain. For instance, linker targeting Windows will require object file in PE format for supporting Windows libraries, and additional formats if the compiler in the tool-chain output to one of these other formats like ELF.